# How to add multiple custom fonts to the Neve Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

I am pretty new to coding and currently struggling with a code snippet.

I am using the Neve WordPress theme and I want to add some custom fonts. The code to do this in documentation is posted below. I want to add more than just one custom font and can't get it done, because I keep getting PHP errors.

Here's my code:

```
function add_custom_font() { 
    $font_path_ttf = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/BionicKidSimpleSlanted.ttf';
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'BionicKidSimpleSlanted';
        src: url( <?php echo esc_url($font_path_ttf); ?>)  format('truetype');
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_custom_font');
add_action('customize_controls_print_styles', 'add_custom_font');

function add_custom_fonts($localized_data)
{
    $localized_data['fonts']['Custom'][] = 'BionicKidSimpleSlanted';
    return $localized_data;
}
add_filter('neve_react_controls_localization', 'add_custom_fonts');
```

Comment: Hi! Please [edit] your question to include the errors you are getting. Just from looking at your code, though, it seems like you put an extra `<?php` and `?>` by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple fonts by simply adding `$localized_data['fonts']['Custom'][] = 'ExtraFontName';` before return in `add_custom_fonts` function.

**Example:**

```
function add_custom_font() { 
    $font_path_ttf = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/BionicKidSimpleSlanted.ttf';
    $extra_font_path_ttf = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/ExtraFontName.ttf';
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'BionicKidSimpleSlanted';
        src: url(<?php echo esc_url($font_path_ttf); ?>)  format('truetype');
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'ExtraFontName';
        src: url(<?php echo esc_url($extra_font_path_ttf); ?>)  format('truetype');
    }

    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_custom_font');
add_action('customize_controls_print_styles', 'add_custom_font');

function add_custom_fonts($localized_data) {

    // First Font
    $localized_data['fonts']['Custom'][] = 'BionicKidSimpleSlanted';
    // Second Font
    $localized_data['fonts']['Custom'][] = 'ExtraFontName';

    return $localized_data;
}
add_filter('neve_react_controls_localization', 'add_custom_fonts');
```